# Iterating through files in folder is very slow in qt

Tags: c++, performance, qt

I am iterating through all files in a folder (recursively though all its sub folders) but this is extremely slow..it almost never returns. I could put this in a thread but even than it will not be practical with this speed. Here is my function

```
int MainWindow::searchXmlFiles(QString rootDir)
{
    xmlFileModel->clear(); // xmlFileModel is QStanardItemModel

    int count = 0;

    XmlFile xmlFile;
    QString xmlFilePath;

    QDirIterator iter( rootDir, QStringList() << "*.xml", QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

    QDir dir( ui->lineEditSourceFolder->text() );

    while(iter.hasNext() )
    {
        qDebug() << iter.next();

        xmlFilePath = iter.filePath();

        xmlCollection = xmlFile.openXmlFile( xmlFilePath );

        QStandardItem * item = new QStandardItem( QIcon(":/icons/xmlfile.ico") , dir.relativeFilePath( xmlFilePath) );

        xmlFileModel->appendRow( item );

        count++;
    }

    QString fileCount = QString("Total of %1 file(s) will be converted from `%2` folder").arg( QString::number(count), rootDir);

    ui->labelXmlFileCount->setText( fileCount );

    return count;
}
```

Is this slow speed really expected? Is there way to do the same thing faster?

**Update**

After comment by Jeremey, if I comment all the work inside the loop (xmlFile.openXmlFile() and QStandardItem creation), it gets quite fast, takes like 3 seconds. If I leave QStandardItem creation there, it takes about 7 seconds/

Comment: How much faster does this function get if you comment out the calls to tier.filePath(), xmlFile.openXmlFile(), the creation of QStandardItems and the appending of them to the xmlFileModel?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner good suggestion, that actually speeds it up significantly but now it takes 7 seconds for one particularly large folder (2.5 gb). It seems like previously maybe getting stuck in that function as well.

Comment: It sounds like you're building an insanely large model, which may well trigger repeated UI updates, which (because these components may need to re-layout on updates) could well mean a traversal of the existing nodes, which would make your whole loop N^2.

Comment: If openXmlFile() is opening each file and reading in (and parsing as XML) the file's contents, that operation probably takes a long time.  Perhaps you can find some way to only open and read an XML file when it is necessary to do so, rather than reading them all up-front.

Comment: @SebastianRedl The model is not that big, it only fetches 300 files which is to be displayed from all 2.5 gb folder. This wouldn't be a typical folder (far from it), I am just testing worst case scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QDir::entryList() to get full list of XML files at once and then iterate through QStringList of file names.

Comment: To improve performance of QStandartItemModel block all signals from the model, do appending of rows, reenable the signals and then invoke reset() slot of the QAbstractItemView's descendant.